# ASP.Net Core Web API MVC

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm a tad confused - I've created an ASP.Net Core Web API MVC Project and testing out a couple of the pre-implemented endpoints but consistently getting the following response `"{"id":["The value 'values' is not valid."]}".`

```
target url : https://url/api/values

namespace Project.Api.Controllers
{
    [Route("api)]
    [ApiController]
    public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: Which endpoint are you calling? And could you show us just a bit more (relevant) code? The route by default is `api/<RouterName>` so you might be using an incorrect route.

Comment: please post the entire controller class as well as the `RouteConfig`. If you can include an example of the URI you are making a request to as well, that'd be great

Comment: I've not changed anything outside of the default setup

Comment: The default project template works so there was either a change to it or you're not making a request to a valid route correctly- please post the relevant code so we can help

Comment: @GregH Updated the post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `[Route("api")]` annotation on your controller so your `Get` method will be accessible at `localhost:port/api` instead of `localhost:port/api/values`.

If you change the annotation to  `[Route("api/[controller]")]` then the current route you are requesting (`localhost:port/api/values`) will work